# Mystery of the Dead Outlets

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker

I'm completely stumped on what should be an easy problem to solve. My parents home recently lost power to the lights and outlets in their back 2 bedrooms.  No breakers are thrown.  Here's where it gets strange.

One outlet in one of the rooms (that should be on the same circuit) is working fine. I've rewired that outlet from backstab to using the screws. No luck! As I've done debugging with the power off, I've found something strange. There is continuity between Hot and Neutral (black and white).  I've followed it through multiple outlets and it's real.  When I'm in the breaker, I can replicate (with power off of course). With an ohm-meter, that circuit is showing a short between the Neutral bar and its breaker. When the breaker is on, 120V does show between the Hot breaker (when it's on) and the neutral bar.

I've pulled every outlet and light switch to disconnect Hot and Neutrals and the problem remains. I've also looked for the hidden GFCI but still no luck.  I've also put in my AC sniffer and no AC is in any of the outlets or switches that are affected.

One thing in the breaker box that I didn't like was the ground coming in from the service line (connected to one of the Neutral bars) looked like it was melting. The plastic was literally flowing but it wasn't warm to the touch. I did a continuity check between both neutral bars and they were shorted.

The only thing I could possibly think of is that there's a short from a nail/screw somewhere that's bypassing the other outlets. I find it hard to believe it as I would expect the 15A breaker to trip and for me to see some AC current shunted to the other circuits.  With the AC sniffer, there's nothing!

Help!

Comment: When you say you see continuity between the breaker and neutral bar with power off, is that with the master breaker off and the individual breaker on? If so, you’re reading through other loads on other breakers. Try turning off the individual breaker too.

Comment: You realize ordinary loads that are plugged in and switched on will present as low ohmic values in the sub-1000 ohm range, right?  A 1500W heater will be 10 ohms.  Further, many loads are non-linear - they have *much* lower resistance off than on - incandescents, motors, transformers, and any power supply with capacitors, to name a few. When probed with a very low DVM voltage, they may present as a dead short.

Comment: Are there any loads plugged in when you are doing continuity tests?

Comment: Any lights on the circuit being one of the most common, next transformers like a doorbell or furnace these are quite often hard wired without a switch.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Master breaker is off. All outlets do not have anything plugged in. Light switches turned to off positions. Even if there is something like a light or load I'm missing, the problem still remains that two rooms full of switches and receptacles are dead.